# Outputting line of string search in python

Tags: python, string, search

Im new to python and Im trying to search a text file for a particular string, then output the whole line which contains that string. However, I want to do this as two separate files. Main file contains the following code;

```
def searchNoCase():
   f = open('text.txt')
   for line in f:
         if searchWord() in f:
            print(line)
   else:
    print("No result")

   f.close()



def searchWord(stuff):
      word=stuff
     return word
```

File 2 contains the following code

```
import main

def bla():
  main.searchWord("he")
```

Im sure this is a simple fix but I cant seem to figure it out. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There are a number of fundamental issues here with the code. Mostly though, you never try to call `searchNoCase()` so no file is opened. This code is quite a way from ever running though.

Comment: Oh yes. Other than calling searchNoCase(), what else am i missing?

Comment: Well, 1) `searchWord(stuff)` does absolutely nothing - it gives you back whatever value you sent to it. 2) No code in File 2 ever runs because you don't call the function. 3) `if searchWord() in f:` why are you looking for a function in the file? 4) The indentation is all over the place in `searchNoCase()`. There are still more. I think you would find it easier to focus on getting the task done in a single file.

Comment: That is the point. I want to define a particular string in file 2. Then pass the string by calling the function searchWord. And at last searching the document based on the defined string and outputting the result. I want to do this as two separate files

Comment: I understand that but, at the same time, there's a fundamental misunderstanding of some basic python concepts. The fact that you want to call this function from another script is further compounding the list of concepts you have to learn (for example, do you have an `__init__.py` file? Do you know why you have to use `if __name__ == '__main__':`?). Focus on getting functions that are correct and can do the job in a single script, _then_ worry about the main task.

Comment: Already. Well more learning it is then. Thanks anyway

Comment: Let me see if I can quickly get a working example that I can annotate for you, it may help push you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, that would be fantastic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Python 3 so I need to check exactly what changed with `__init__.py` but in the meantime, create an empty script with that name in the same directory as the following files.

I've tried to cover a few different topics for you to read up on. For example, the exception handler is basically useless here because `input` (in Python 3) always returns a string but it's something you would have to worry about.

This is `main.py`

```
def search_file(search_word):

    # Check we have a string input, otherwise converting to lowercase fails
    try:
        search_word = search_word.lower()

    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)
        # Now break out of the function early and give nothing back
        return None

    # If we didn't fail, the function will keep going

    # Use a context manager (with) to open files. It will close them automatically
    # once you get out of its block

    with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:

            # Break sentences into words
            words = line.split()

            # List comprehention to convert them to lowercase
            words = [item.lower() for item in words]

            if search_word in words:
                return line

    # If we found the word, we would again have broken out of the function by this point
    # and returned that line
    return None
```

This is `file1.py`

```
import main

def ask_for_input():
    search_term = input('Pick a word: ') # use 'raw_input' in Python 2
    check_if_it_exists = main.search_file(search_term)

    if check_if_it_exists:
        # If our function didn't return None then this is considered True
        print(check_if_it_exists)
    else:
        print('Word not found')

ask_for_input()
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very very much!